# Svelte mui Select ignores on:change handler

Tags: material-ui, svelte, smui

I have a basic example of Select control on which I try to attach an onChange handler:

```
<script type="ts">
    import Select, { Option } from '@smui/select';

    const onChange = () => {
        console.log('on change!');
    };

    let fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'];

    let value = 'Orange';
</script>
```

```
    <div>
        <Select bind:value label="Select Menu" on:change={onChange}>
          {#each fruits as fruit}
            <Option value={fruit}>{fruit}</Option>
          {/each}
        </Select>
    
        <pre class="status">Selected: {value}</pre>
      </div>
```

However the event handler is ignored. I am using latest smui and svelte

Comment: How do you even know that there *is* a `change` event? The documentation for `smui` is kinda useless/cannot even be called that.

Comment: I don't know, but it seems like a basic feature to have for a Select control. Actually the only events for which I get an autocomplete in VSCode are focus and blur,which doesn't work either. I might do something wrong though. on:click works, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [component source code](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/packages/select/src/Select.svelte#L505), the correct event is `on:SMUISelect:change`:

```html
<script type="ts">
    import Select, { Option } from '@smui/select';

    const onChange = () => {
        console.log('on change!');
    };

    let fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'];

    let value = 'Orange';
</script>

<div>
    <Select bind:value label="Select Menu" on:SMUISelect:change={onChange}>
        {#each fruits as fruit}
        <Option value={fruit}>{fruit}</Option>
        {/each}
    </Select>

    <pre class="status">Selected: {value}</pre>
</div>
```